# Naviagte firefox sidebars with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keymap

Is there a way for me to navigate through firefox sidebars with shortcuts? The behavior I would expect is pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> after opening sidebar should cycle through the items in the sidebar, but instead the first <kbd>tab</kbd> jumps to the web page.

I use Windows 7 x 64, Firefox 20.0.1, I am primarily looking to navigate `bookmark` and `history` sidebars.

Comment: Interesting question. However it is not possible to answer without more details. Which FF sidebar do you have. On what OS. What version of FF do you have.

Comment: There is no shortcuts for the build in sidebar. Try a add-on sidebar like http://firefox.exxile.net/aios/index.php or others.

Comment: I have the same Firefox and Windows as you Prometheus, but pressing TAB works for me! Ctrl+B opens the bookmarks sidebar, then I press TAB (to move out of the search box), then the [down arrow key] cycle's through the items. I would make this an answer but surely there's a discrepancy.

Comment: @Bort I think vimperator add-on is what is causing the problem for me.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried out the add-on, but it did not solve my problem. Once again, I think it is vimperator that is causing the problem.